# how to change system tablespace's extent_management in oracle

Tags: oracle, dictionary, local, tablespace

i used oracle 19c.

I'm trying to see the difference between a dictionary of tablespaces, local management.

When the first database was created, it was confirmed that the management of the SYSTEM tablespace was local.

The following query was performed when creating a new tablespace.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TABLESPACE1
DATAFILE
    '/TS_DATAFILE1.dbf'
        SIZE 1024000
        AUTOEXTEND OFF
NOLOGGING
DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS STORAGE (
    INITIAL 10240
    NEXT 10240
    MINEXTENTS 2
    MAXEXTENTS 50
    PCTINCREASE 50
)
ONLINE
EXTENT MANAGEMENT
    DICTIONARY
SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT MANUAL
FLASHBACK OFF;
```

But the following error occurred.

**ORA 12913- Cannot create dictionary managed tablespace**

I know that the 19c version is created as local by default, and it seems to be necessary to change the SYSTEM tablespace to a dictionary in order to solve the above error.

But I don't know how to change it.
Please advise.

Comment: You can't change a locally managed tablespace into a dictionary managed tablespace.  You might be able to recreate the database with a dictionary managed `system` tablespace (I don't recall off the top of my head whether that was even still an option in 19c).  But given that dictionary managed tablespaces have been on their way out for quite a long time, I'd seriously question why you'd want to bother-- it's been a lot of years since I've run across a dictionary managed tablespace in the wild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your system tablespace is already locally managed, you cannot create a tablespace that is dictionary managed.

Also check this info from **oracle**.

- **Cause**: Attempt to create dictionary managed tablespace in database which has **system tablespace** as locally managed.
- **Action**: Create a locally managed tablespace.

The extents of a locally managed tablespace are managed efficiently in the tablespace by the Oracle database server itself. Dictionary-managed option is
provided only for backward compatibility.